# Image cropping problem

Tags: css, photoshop

When I copy a layer in photoshop, then I want to merge it with canvas, I crop it, but it's getting smaller. I want to save its original size! Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the cropped version you are pasting into has a relatively bigger size. That might be the reason you are feeling like it getting smaller. Observer closely what is the zoom level.

Comment: No, it's okay! both images are 100%

Comment: He's saying that the image1 is 1000x1000pxs but image2 is only 10x10 px so when image2 is pasted into image1, it'd appear very small!